# Apache Crunch: how to create custom counters

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to add custom [counters](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html)  to my [Apache Crunch](http://crunch.apache.org/) job using org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context.getCounter API. Does anybody know how to get access to the context from the Crunch pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious place to look would be

> org.apache.crunch.DoFn#getCounter

and guess what? It's there...